# Node - Merge dynamic amount of arrays together - alternate the items in the result array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a bunch of arrays of different length holding objects of the same types. What I want is to merge all these arrays into one final array. The issue I have is that the items need to alternate in the final result array.

so if for example one array only holds one value to altenate the results until there is no element in the shortest length array and continue with just the others still holding values.

```js
const arr1 = [arr1Obj, arr1Obj, arr1Obj]
const arr2 = [arr2Obj, arr2Obj, arr2Obj]
const arr3 = [arr3obj]

//no pre-defined amount of arrays, could be only one array or 10+

//output desired
[arr1Obj, arr2Obj, arr3Obj, arr1Obj, arr2Obj, arr1Obj, arr2Obj]
```

My approach was just using a bunch of nested for-loops which I am sure is not the best way of doing this. I am wondering, how would the shortest most performant es6 way look alike? Preferably without using modules like lodash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the sequence we wish for.

We start by getting the max array length using [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), then we use `Array.from()` to create our output array, using `Array.reduce()` to append each element as we iterate over the arrays, flattening at the end:

```js
const arr1 = ['arr1Obj', 'arr1Obj', 'arr1Obj']
const arr2 = ['arr2Obj', 'arr2Obj', 'arr2Obj']
const arr3 = ['arr3Obj']

// Sort our input by length, we want the longest array first...
const arrays = [arr1, arr2, arr3]; 

const maxLength = Math.max(...arrays.map(a => a.length));

const result = Array.from({ length: maxLength }, (v, idx) => arrays.reduce((acc, arr) => {
    if (idx < arr.length) {
        acc.push(arr[idx]);
    }
    return acc;
}, [])).flat();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This changes array order, which I don't think the OP wants.

Comment: does it? I tested the code and it looks like it is doing exactly what I wanted. The output is like my pseudo code in initial post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce` to `n` arrays with the `j`th elements and then `.push` all of their elements:

```
let arrs = [
    [1,2,3],
    [2,undefined,'4',6,90,3.14],
    [1,0,-1,5],
    [],
    [100, 300, -Infinity]
];

let merged = [];
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < arrs.length; i++, j++) {
  merged.push(...arrs.reduce((a, c) => {
   if (c.length > j) a.push(c[j]);
   return a;
  }, []));
}
```

Comment: that doesnt solve the problem mentioned above. That is just generally merging arrays (not even dynamically).

Comment: @BitQueen I've come up with an ugly method to do it; it doesn't change items order, and it allows `undefined`s; I hope I can clean the code after a bit of brainstorming :)